# Best style for calling a function on each row with do() in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
  df <- data_frame(
    my_x1 = c(1, 11, 21), 
    my_x2 = c(10, 20, 30), 
    my_y1 = c(100, 200, 300), 
    my_y2 = c(400, 500, 600))
```

For each of those rows, I want to interpolate between points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), evaluated at all integers between x1 and x2.

This is what I'm doing right now, which is producing the output I want, but IMO the code itself is a little messy, with all the ".$" symbols everywhere and the column renaming in a second step:

```
  df2 <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    do(., data.frame(
      approx(
          x=c(.$my_x1, .$my_x2), 
          y=c(.$my_y1, .$my_y2), 
          xout=.$my_x1:.$my_x2))) %>%
    rename(my_x = x, my_y = y) %>%
    as_data_frame()
```

Style-wise, is this the correct convention for using do() to call a function on each row of a data frame, or is there a better way?

Comment: I'd transpose and make it a column-wise operation instead of row-wise. But it's just style, there's no right or wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. Could you elaborate on the transpose approach? After the transpose, each column consists of four rows containing values for (x1, x2, y1, y2). How do you call approx() from there?

(And understood that it's just a matter of style; I'm just trying to get a handle on any best practices to improve code readability.)

Comment: Perhaps I didn't read carefully enough, this looks pretty good to me actually. The way I would have initially approached it would probably be to write a quick wrapper for approx that takes a vector (x1, x2, y1, y2) and returns what you want. And really, since there's no grouping (at least in this example) I'd probably just use `apply`.

Comment: The `.` in `do(., data.frame(` is not necessary and could be simplified into `do(data.frame(`. Also I would prefer to call `seq.int` over the `:` here. Mostly because I find it easier to read.

Comment: For questions of style, perhaps [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) is better suited.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @shadow. Good points. And I wasn't aware of CodeReview; I'll keep that in mind for next time.